# Java gender char invalid

Tags: java, string, char, switch-statement

I'm attempting to test whether the gender char is invalid and if so, to print an error message explaining the input requirements and then ending the program.  If the gender is valid (`M` or `F` or `m` or `f`) continue to execute the program.  I also need to use a switch statement on the gender variable to determine which formula to use.  My printed display should read:

> The child's adult height would be 5.58.

The height should be displayed using `printf()` and in 2 decimal places.

Here is what I have so far that is not computing correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Workshop3GenderModification {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int gender;
gender = 'M';
gender = 'F';

double cheight=0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//father height

System.out.print("Enter your father height in feet ");
int ffeet=input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter father height in inches ");
int finches=input.nextInt();

//mother height
System.out.print("Enter mother height in feet ");
int mfeet=input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter mother height in inches ");
int minches=input.nextInt();

int mheight = mfeet * 12 + minches;
int fheight = ffeet * 12 + finches;

// child gender

System.out.print("Enter M for male or F for female ");
gender = input.next().charAt (0);
// male or female
input.nextLine();

switch (gender){
  case 'M':
  cheight =(int)((fheight * 13/12.0)+ mheight)/2;
  break;
}

switch (gender){
  case 'F' :
  cheight =(int)((mheight * 12/13.0) + fheight)/2 ;
  break;
}

int cfeet= (int)cheight/12;
int cinched= (int)cheight%12;
double aheight=(cfeet/cinched);
System.out.print(cfeet +"'" + cinched + "\"");
System.out.printf("will be the adult child's height" +"%.2f", aheight);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem that you need help with?

Comment: thank you!  I need to have an error msg explaining the input requirements if a user doesn't enter specifically "M" "F" ending the program.  If the gender is valid the program should continue executing.  Also the final output isn't displaying correctly as "The child's adult height would be 6.45'."

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code has two switch statements. You probably want one:

```
switch (gender){
  case 'M':
    cheight =(int)((fheight * 13/12.0)+ mheight)/2;
    break;
  case 'F' :
    cheight =(int)((mheight * 12/13.0) + fheight)/2 ;
    break;
}
```

If you want to deal with the problem of invalid input, you could do this with a default case:

```
switch (gender){
  case 'M':
    cheight =(int)((fheight * 13/12.0)+ mheight)/2;
    break;
  case 'F' :
    cheight =(int)((mheight * 12/13.0) + fheight)/2 ;
    break;
  default:
    invalidInput = true; // you'll want to declare this above and 
                         // initialize it to false
}
```

Now you can check to see if invalidInput has been set to true, and if so, respond appropriately.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!  so I did that, but I haven't learned the default case yet, meaning I'm not sure how to declare it above (sorry, I'm such a NOOB!!!)

Comment: Here's some documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two switch statements and no default switch case. If you only want the gender to work with 'M', 'm', 'F', 'f', then let the case fall-through for similar characters, ie. M-m, and F-f.

```
switch(gender) {
    case 'M':
    case 'm':
        cheight =(int)((fheight * 13/12.0)+ mheight)/2;
        break;
    case 'F':
    case 'f':
        cheight =(int)((mheight * 12/13.0) + fheight)/2;
        break;
    default:
        System.exit(0);   // stop process
        break;
}

// if a F, f, M, or m were not entered, this will never be reached
NumberFormat nm = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
System.out.println( "output: " + nm.format(cheight) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just noticed the edits at the bottom!